# Issue with code for retrieving an image from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, image-caching

Hi I am getting this error when I implement this code **Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'** I know what it means but is there a way I can change the code below to work?

var userProfile: UserProfile?{

```
    didSet{

        let url = URL(string: (userProfile?.photoURL)!)

        if let url = url as? URL{


            KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url as Resource) { (image, error, cache, imageURL) in
                           self.profileImage.image = image
                           self.profileImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                       }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Is  the type of ``userProfile?.photoURL`` a string or a URL object? If its a URL object the URL(string: ) is redundant.

Comment: it is a url, what can I put in there instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the solution:

```
var userProfile: UserProfile?{
    didSet{


        if let url = userProfile?.photoURL {


            KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url as Resource) { (image, error, cache, imageURL) in
                           self.profileImage.image = image
                           self.profileImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                       }

        }



    }
}
```